# Test functions that have an effect on firebase (firestore, database, storage) offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, mocking

How to do a unit test for functions that have an effect on ( firestore, real-time database, and storage ) offline

for example, write a unit test for `setDoc`

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function setDoc(path, data, merge = true){
    return admin.firestore().doc(path).set(data, {merge: merge})
}

module.exports = {
    setDoc
}
```

I can't use `firebase-function-testing` because `setDoc` is not a firebase function

also, I don't want to use `@firebase/testing` because it is deprecated

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you are trying to deploy using firebase? What version of firebase you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Firebase Emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQkfYk4t5zs), everything is being rendered locally and won't interact with your firebase. The Firebase Local Emulator Suite runs different emulators, for example authentication, Firestore, functions, etc.  You can use it for development or testing purposes.

It is recommended to test everything locally, before trying the instance in your cloud. You can use any editor of your choice (the example video provided uses angular).

Here is the link for the [Firebase Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) and [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests).

Here is a very [good lab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-emulator#0) to get familiar with the emulator.